# jboss 4.2.2 GA under windows server 2008 - possibly firewall related?

Tags: jboss, windows-server-2008, firewall

I've been running JBoss 4.2.2 GA for ages now under XP 64 and server 2003.  Recently I decided to install server 2008 (x64) over my xp 64 installation and use it as my desktop as so many people love to tout...

Unfortunately now when I start JBoss 'something' - and i am assuming it's somehow the windows firewall - prevents connections from working properly.

Nothing has changed, jboss was on a different partition, it's based on java so all that is different might be the jvm (default java_home is x64 version: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin)

I can fire up JBoss and go to http://localhost:8080... but i can NOT go to "http://{hostname}:8080"

i have disabled the firewall time and again - unblocked TCP port 8080 - NOTHING works...

Thanks!

UPDATE: tried it with x86 based java - no difference

Comment: Which IP or host is jboss listening for connections on? If it's only listening on localhost, that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you're binding the socket to localhost. If you add the command line option "-b 0.0.0.0" to the call to run.jar, it should fix your problem.

There's probably a more proper way to accomplish the same thing through a property. A quick Google search suggests jboss.bind.address, although many results suggest the above command line option instead.

Comment: gah - i'd forgotten about this blasted property!!!  thanks Matthew - finally one of my questions "answered"...